# fsolve a polynomial in matlab not working

Tags: matlab, math, polynomial-approximations

(5/(r^2*9))- ((2)/(9*(6-r)^2)) - r = 0

would like to solve the above polynomial in matlab:

```
fun= (5/(r^2*9))- ((2)/(9*(6-r)^2))-r;
x0 = 10; % some initial point
x = fsolve(fun,x0)
```

Not working! 
Error: Undefined operator '.^' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Comment: In your post, `r` is undefined, `fun` is not defined as an anoymous function and `.^` isn't used anywhere. The error message has nothing to do with the code that you have posted. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks @Thales for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) and properly [vectorize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) the function and it should work:

```
fun= @(r) (5./(r.^2*9))- ((2)./(9*(6-r).^2))-r;
x0 = 1; % some initial point (10 is not a good initial estimate)
x = fsolve(fun,x0)
```